# Calculating number of mines surrounding a cell in 2d array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, char, 2d, minesweeper

Hi so basically I'm trying to make a beginner version of minesweeper but i got a bit stuck.
I'm able to get to the stage where i have a 2d array of chars while'*' means mine and ^ doesn't. The part where i'm stuck is changing the '^' with the number of mines surrounding it what my code does is return a 2d array but instead of numbers, I'm getting weird questions marks.

here are my functions.

```java
static char[][] calculatemines(char[][] h) {
    int height = h.length;
    int width = h[0].length;

    char[][] newh = new char[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < newh.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newh[0].length; j++) {
            if(h[i][j]=='*') {
                newh[i][j]='*';
            } else
                newh[i][j]= (char) numberofmines(h,height,width);
        }
    }

    return newh;
}
```

and this s the second function

```java
private static int numberofmines(char[][] f, int height, int width) {

    int numberofmines = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            int iStart = Math.max(0, i - 1);
            int iEnd = Math.min(height, i + 1);

            int jStart = Math.max(0, j - 1);
            int jEnd = Math.min(width, j + 1);

            for (int squareI = iStart; squareI < iEnd; squareI++) {
                for (int squareJ = jStart; squareJ < jEnd; squareJ++) {
                    if (f[squareI][squareJ] == '*') {
                        numberofmines++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return numberofmines;
}
```

Thank you for all the help :)

Comment: You are casting an int e.g. 5 to a char - this will be its ascii value.  See an asciitable for more info.  Usually whenever you are casting, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are casting the int from `numberofmines()` to a char, which means you are getting the [ASCII value](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html). You can add 48 (`'0'` has the ASCII value of 48) to get the the original number

```
newh[i][j] = (char)(numberofmines(h,height,width) + 48);
```

Edit:

You don't need to iterate over the all array in `numberofmines()`, just the surrounding cells

```
else {
    newh[i][j] = (char)(numberofmines(h, h.length, h[0].length, i, j) + 48);
}

private static int numberofmines(char[][] f, int height, int width, int i, int j) {
    int iStart = Math.max(0, i - 1);
    int iEnd = Math.min(height, i + 2);

    int jStart = Math.max(0, j - 1);
    int jEnd = Math.min(width, j + 2);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: or add the char `'0'`

Comment: Still not working, now I'm getting a letter but the same letter for all the cells that are not mines

Comment: `numberofmines(h,height,width);` - values of these variables don't change, so I guess you would get the same results

Comment: changes height with i and width with j but now im getting wrong numbers.

Comment: Rows:  5
Coloumns:  5
 Enter a Valid P 0.2
0 0 0 0 0 
* 0 * * 0 
0 1 2 3 5 
0 2 4 6 : 
0 * 4 6 :

Comment: still not calculating it right, for example i'm getting 0 for a cell that has a mine just next to it.

Comment: @NadavSuissa Updated `iEnd` and `jEnd`.